# Add Week OF column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add `df['Week Of']` column in a pandas data frame based on date column. Week starts from Monday and ends on Sunday.

My input column looks like this.

```
Date (mm/dd/yyyy)
    2019-04-01
    2019-04-08
    2019-04-30
    2019-05-01
    2019-05-02
    2019-05-03
    2019-05-04
    2019-05-05
```

I want output like

```
Week Of
2019-04-01
2019-04-08
2019-04-29
2019-04-29
2019-04-29
2019-04-29
2019-04-29
2019-04-29
```

So here clearly 2019-04-01 was Monday so it's giving the same date, however, 2019-04-30 was Tuesday but as my weekday starts from Monday so I want to count it on Mondays date which is 2019-04-29.

I tried with below apporach which seems not working.

```
df['Week of'] = df['Date (mm/dd/yyyy)'] - \
                                          ((df['Date (mm/dd/yyyy)'].dt.weekday + 1) % 7)\
                                              .astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

please help.

This has been marked duplicate but my question is quite different. I want to add a column of week based on Date Column, so If Date in date column is 2019-04-01 which is monday and from this day next 7 days would come under same date and after 7 days next 7 days would come under next monday which will 2019-04-08.

Comment: `df['Date'] = df['Date (mm/dd/yyyy)'].dt.to_period('W').apply(lambda r: r.start_time)`

Comment: @jezrael Can you please help me to understand how can I add the week_of column where the condition is like if the date is 2019-04-01 which is Monday so next 7 days would count under 2019-04-01 and so on. if suppose after 2019-04-01 mentioned date is 2019-04-30 which is Tuesday so it should come under the week 2019-04-29 which is monday.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused - solution not woking? It convert to week period and then get first part of periods in `df['Date'] = df['Date (mm/dd/yyyy)'].dt.to_period('W').apply(lambda r: r.start_time) `

Comment: @jezrael, it's working. I just want to understand how it's working

Comment: If it's working, then the question really is a duplicate, as this answer was from the other question. As for why it works, it's converting the date to **W**eekly period, then getting the `start_time` of that period.